# A $k$-linear graded automorphism of $A$ is not necessarily an automorphism of algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group, graded-algebras

Hi I'm studying the paper "Twisted Graded Algebras and Equivalences of Graded Categories" by J.J Zhang. At one point the statement is made "Note that a $k$-linear graded automorphism of $A$ is not necessarily an automorphism of algebras". 
Where $A$ is a graded algebra $A=\bigoplus_{g\in\mathbb{G}}A_{g}$ 
Any ideas to understand it better or find a counter example? 
Also, if you've studied on this topic, I would appreciate if you've any reference.
Thanks so much.

Comment: $A$ is a $\mathbb{G}$-graded algebra: $A=\bigoplus_{g\in\mathbb{G}}A_{g}$

Comment: Yes, it is a group. With respect to algebra.

Comment: Yes sir. What I have understood, is that the graded k-linear automorphism preserves the degrees of each " grade or indexing" of the graded algebra A.

Comment: https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/135651/plms0281.pdf?sequence=1
Page 284 of the paper. Second paragraph

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Can you give me some reference about graded algebras, graded homomorphisms and these topics?